# Datatables pagination button styling problem, no CSS there

Tags: datatables, pagination

[image: pagination error]

There are no error in console, I have no idea about that

Answer (score 0):

it's because the jquery.datatables.min.js I import without jquery.datatables.min.css,

please someone at datatables they need to give error for this